# Blackmagick Decklink as webRTC source

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, webrtc

I'm using the latest Blackmagic drivers (11.1) and Ubuntu 19. I would like to use my Decklink Duo as a webRTC source but unfortunately in Chrome or Firefox I can't select any Decklink input. This happens only in Linux. In Windows 10, everything is fine and I can select any of the four input devices with no problems at all

Can anybody help me?

Thank you very much in advance,
Davide